# UWP: x:Bind does not handle font icon correctly

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm try to pass my Icon text through x:Bind Icon like this

X:Bind Icon is [image]

```
<ui:ButtonWithIcon IconContent="{x:Bind Icon}"
                   Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                   Margin="0,20,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource RoundFontButtonStyle}"/>
```

However, It gave me this result:
[image]
If I change the code to this, the font icon do show correctly:

```
<ui:ButtonWithIcon IconContent="&#xE1D3;"
                   Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                   Margin="0,20,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource RoundFontButtonStyle}"
                  />
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#xE1D3;` is a XAML escape character, that is, it is just an expression in XAML.

In C#, as a unicode character, it can be written like this:

```cs
Name = "\uE1D3";
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard Zhang, this was indeed the mistake that I made.